# Does Apple allow "Fake iOS Frameworks"?

Tags: objective-c, ios, frameworks

I recently stumbled across [templates by Karl Stenerud](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework), and I find them amazing. I was wondering if Apple allows them, of if Apple is against them. I just want to be sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using them in my apps too.  Since they're static frameworks, there's nothing in them that Apple won't allow in the app store.  They're pretty much just a static library with media files bundled.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure "Fake" is the right word for them, maybe "custom" is better. Yes, custom frameworks are allowed. Only access to Apples private API will cause a rejection.

Comment: "Fake" just means it's not technically a framework (in Apple's sense of the word).  There's two main projects for custom frameworks on iOS, hosted on GitHub: https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework and https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework.  From the former: "A fake framework is a bundle target with a .framework extension and some post-build scripts to generate the fat library for the .framework."